# Implement two internal Python types simultaneuosly

Tags: python, types, metaclass

I'm trying to change the return type of a function from `set` to `list`. For a smooth transition, the idea was to do an in-place deprecation and temporarily return a type that is both a `set` *and* a `list`. But I'm not sure whether it possible to derive from two internal Python types because:

```py
>>> class ListSet(list, set):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

In general the goal is to have a type that behaves like a sorted set (I think then it would be pretty much the same as a list and set) but also works with type checks (and ideally also works with MyPy):

```
thing = class.method_with_updated_return_type()
print(isinstance(thing, set))  # True
print(isinstance(thing, list))  # True
```

My idea would otherwise have been to override the `__instancecheck__` method of `ListSet`'s metaclass, to something like

```
class Meta(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        return isinstance(instance, (set, list))

class ListSet(metaclass=Meta):
    # implement all set and list methods
```

Is something like this possible in Python?

Comment: Set and list semantics are too different for this to be reasonable even if the Python internals didn't make this impossible.

Comment: Seriously, this would not help smooth the transition. It would do the exact opposite. You would have so many weird problems if Python had actually let you do this when you tried.

Comment: It sms like you want an "ordered set". That is still very different from a "thing that is both a set or a list depengind on it being used by old or newly written code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, no, nothing short of inheriting directly from `set` or  `list` will make an instance of a custom class return "True" for an `isinstance` call. And there are several reasons why one class can't inherit from both at the sametime, and even if you'd code such a class in native code, or modify it with ctypes so that it would return True for such an `isinstance` check, the resulting class would likely crash your Python interpreter when used.

On the other hand, the mechanisms provided by the Abstract Base Classes and the `__instancecheck__`, `__subclasscheck__`, `__subclasshook__` and `register` methods allow one to answer "True" if asked if an instance of anyone class is an instance of the custom class making use of these methods. That is: your custom class could answer, if asked, that an arbitrary list or set is an instance of itself, like in `myobj = set((1,2,3)); isinstance(myobj, MySpecialClass) -> True`- but not the other way around: `isinstance(MySpecialClass(), set)` will always return False.

What there is in order to allow similar mechanisms is that the recomendation is that one codes for *prococols*, not for specific classes. There is, any well-written code should always do `isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Set)` or `collections.abc.Sequence` and never `isinstance(..., set)` (or `list`). Then anyone can register a custom class as a subclass of those, and the test would be `True`:

```
from collections.abc import MutableSet, Sequence

class MyClass(MutableSet):  
    #  <-NB. don't try to inherit _also_ from Sequence here. See bellow.


    # code mandatory methods for MutableSet according to
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html, 
    # plus customize all mandadory _and_ derivative methods
    # for a mutable sequence, in order to have your
    # desired "ordered mutable set" behavior here.

# After the class body, do:
Sequence.register(MyClass)
```

The call to `Sequence.register` will register `MyClass` as a virtual subclass of Sequence, and any well behaved code, that tests for the protocol, via collections.abc.Sequence instance check, or, better yet, code that just uses the object as it needs  allows incorrect objects to fail at runtime, will just work. I fyou can get rid of any "isinstance" checks, just coding an appropriate implementation of "MutableSet" can give you an "ordered set" that works like you'd like, with no worries about arbitrary checks for the object type.

That is not hard at all: you can just implement the needed methods, initialize a list holding the actial data in your class  `__init__`, update the list on all content-modifying calls for the Set, and iterate on the list

```
from collections.abc import MutableSet

class OrderedSet(MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, initial=()):
        self.data = list()
        self.update(initial)
        
    def update(self, items):
        for item in items:
            self.add(item)
            
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self.data
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def add(self, item):
        if item not in self.data:
            self.data.append(item)
        
    def discard(self, item):
        self.data.remove(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"OrderedSet({self.data!r})"
```

If you can't change hardcoded tests for instances of "set" or "list", however, there is nothing that you can do.